# Unable to detect wifi networks in xbuntu (already tried every solution proposed on askubuntu)

Tags: networking, wireless, xubuntu, realtek

The wifi was working. I closed my laptop. I opened my laptop. The wifi wasn't working anymore, specifically no wifi is found. I tried restarting the network manager, rebooting the PC, trying every solution found on the web, nothing.

All the information about my system are here https://pastebin.com/jNP35arP .
The info are generated by running

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && chmod +x wireless-info &&   ./wireless-info
```

while connected by USB tethering to an android phone.

the output of `dmesg | grep 8821ce` is:

```
[    4.312082] 8821ce: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    4.315335] 8821ce: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    4.322727] RTW: rtl8821ce v5.2.5_1.26055.20180108.1
[    4.322729] RTW: rtl8821ce BT-Coex version = COEX20170310-1212
[    4.323011] rtl8821ce 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    4.349877] RTW: rtw_read_efuse_from_file /system/etc/wifi/wifi_efuse_8821ce.map is not readable
[    4.358635] Modules linked in: snd_seq gpu_sched btusb ttm uvcvideo btrtl input_leds videobuf2_vmalloc snd_seq_device hp_wmi btbcm 8821ce(OE+) sparse_keymap serio_raw wmi_bmof drm_kms_helper videobuf2_memops btintel k10temp snd_timer videobuf2_v4l2 bluetooth drm videobuf2_common i2c_algo_bit videodev snd fb_sys_fops syscopyarea mc ecdh_generic sysfillrect cfg80211 sysimgblt ecc soundcore joydev hp_accel lis3lv02d input_polldev hp_wireless mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic i2c_amd_mp2_pci usbhid hid nvme psmouse i2c_piix4 ahci r8169 libahci realtek nvme_core wmi i2c_scmi video
[    4.358775]  ? _rtw_malloc+0x2d/0x2f [8821ce]
[    4.358828]  rtw_wiphy_register+0x26/0x53 [8821ce]
[    4.358872]  ? rtw_wiphy_register+0x26/0x53 [8821ce]
[    4.358915]  rtw_cfg80211_ndev_res_register+0x19/0x5b [8821ce]
[    4.358956]  rtw_os_ndev_register+0x116/0x196 [8821ce]
[    4.358998]  rtw_os_ndevs_register+0x9d/0x12f [8821ce]
[    4.359039]  rtw_os_ndevs_init+0x29/0x3f [8821ce]
[    4.359079]  rtw_drv_init+0x3e0/0xaa3 [8821ce]
[    4.359136]  rtw_drv_entry+0x78/0x1000 [8821ce]
[    4.359224] WARNING: CPU: 5 PID: 390 at /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.2.5_1.26055.20180108.1/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:1514 rtw_os_ndev_register+0xbb/0x196 [8821ce]
[    4.359224] Modules linked in: snd_seq gpu_sched btusb ttm uvcvideo btrtl input_leds videobuf2_vmalloc snd_seq_device hp_wmi btbcm 8821ce(OE+) sparse_keymap serio_raw wmi_bmof drm_kms_helper videobuf2_memops btintel k10temp snd_timer videobuf2_v4l2 bluetooth drm videobuf2_common i2c_algo_bit videodev snd fb_sys_fops syscopyarea mc ecdh_generic sysfillrect cfg80211 sysimgblt ecc soundcore joydev hp_accel lis3lv02d input_polldev hp_wireless mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic i2c_amd_mp2_pci usbhid hid nvme psmouse i2c_piix4 ahci r8169 libahci realtek nvme_core wmi i2c_scmi video
[    4.359282] RIP: 0010:rtw_os_ndev_register+0xbb/0x196 [8821ce]
[    4.359333]  rtw_os_ndevs_register+0x9d/0x12f [8821ce]
[    4.359373]  rtw_os_ndevs_init+0x29/0x3f [8821ce]
[    4.359413]  rtw_drv_init+0x3e0/0xaa3 [8821ce]
[    4.359462]  rtw_drv_entry+0x78/0x1000 [8821ce]
[    4.397495] WARNING: CPU: 5 PID: 390 at /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.2.5_1.26055.20180108.1/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:2748 rtw_os_ndevs_register+0xf6/0x12f [8821ce]
[    4.397497] Modules linked in: snd_seq_midi_event aes_x86_64 crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper snd_rawmidi amd_iommu_v2 fjes(-) snd_seq gpu_sched btusb ttm uvcvideo btrtl input_leds videobuf2_vmalloc snd_seq_device hp_wmi btbcm 8821ce(OE+) sparse_keymap serio_raw wmi_bmof drm_kms_helper videobuf2_memops btintel k10temp snd_timer videobuf2_v4l2 bluetooth drm videobuf2_common i2c_algo_bit videodev snd fb_sys_fops syscopyarea mc ecdh_generic sysfillrect cfg80211 sysimgblt ecc soundcore joydev hp_accel lis3lv02d input_polldev hp_wireless mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic i2c_amd_mp2_pci usbhid hid nvme psmouse i2c_piix4 ahci r8169 libahci realtek nvme_core wmi i2c_scmi video
[    4.397605] RIP: 0010:rtw_os_ndevs_register+0xf6/0x12f [8821ce]
[    4.397679]  rtw_os_ndevs_init+0x29/0x3f [8821ce]
[    4.397733]  rtw_drv_init+0x3e0/0xaa3 [8821ce]
[    4.397813]  rtw_drv_entry+0x78/0x1000 [8821ce]
```

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `dmesg | grep 8821ce`

Comment: Thank you, added.

Comment: Do you have an older 5.3 kernel like -24 or -23 you can boot into to see if it works there?

Comment: Wow, thanks  @Jeremy31 . I booted with a 5.0 -36 kernel and now it works. here again the info with this kernel https://pastebin.com/bZum4LyH . Ideas on how to fix the problem keeping the updated kernel?

Comment: Try `sudo apt install linux-image-5.3.0-24-generic linux-headers-5.3.0-24 linux-headers-5.3.0-24-generic linux-modules-5.3.0-24-generic linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-24-generic`  See if it works in 5.3.0-24

Comment: nothing, I runned that command but same situation as before

Comment: If that is the case, you may want to switch back to the 4.15 kernels as the 5.0 kernels go EOL later this month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time I found the solution in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/762255/763097

Press `ESC` on booting, in grub go into the System Setup section, **disable Secure Boot**.

Wifi is back